# Navigation bar drop down over a image

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
               <meta charset="utf-8">
               <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
              <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
             <link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
               <link href="css/welcome.css" rel="stylesheet">
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>VMS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Visitor Mangement System</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="{{URL::to('logout')}}">
          <span style="color:white"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="{{URL::to('register')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{URL::to('login')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Visitor<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('visitorlogin')}}">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('visitorregisterandcheckin')}}">Register and Check In</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('bookedcheckin')}}">Booked Check In</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('visitorcheckin')}}">Check In</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('visitorcheckout')}}">Check Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Employee<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('employeelogin')}}">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('employeecheckin')}}">Check In</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('employeecheckout')}}">Check Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Administrator<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('adminlogin')}}">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('admincheckin')}}">Check In</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{URL::to('admincheckout')}}">Check Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </ul>
  @endif
    </div>
  </nav>
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/img1.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/img2.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000 //changes the speed
})
</script>
</body>
```

i have a navigation bar and below goes a carousel.There is a dropdown in the navigation bar buttons.But the drop  down in navbar is behind the carousel image.I want the dropdown over the carousel.Any Help is most welcome.

Comment: post some images please of what the problem is? Your code can be executed, but there are no images to reproduce the problem. Create a fiddle maybe?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
.dropdown-menu{
   z-index: 123;
}
```

give z-index value higher than the carousel.

Comment: Is that fixed ?

Comment: Nope ...i will embed the code... see whether its is crct

Comment: <style>
    .navbar {

      z-index: 100;
    }

    .carousel {

      z-index: 50;
    }
      </style>

Comment: give z-index to dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

Set a z-index for the two elements

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100; 
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50; 
}
```

A higher [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) will rise above the other.

Comment: <style>
    .navbar {

      z-index: 100;
    }

    .carousel {

      z-index: 50;
    }
      </style> 

Sir,i Tried this but it does not worked

Comment: I tried with position:relative too...But unfortunately i too i did not work for me.

Comment: Could you post your css too?

Comment: That would be too long so i paste the needed code 

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
      z-index: 50;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
      z-index: 50;

}